# Quirky/humorous short book in which all existence is in 1 (or 2) dimensions

Tags: story-identification

This was a very short hardcover book that I read around 2000. I remember it had an odd title with "*Flat*" and/or "*Upside-down*" in the title (possibly some variation on "*The Upside-down War*"?)

I specifically recall it being about a flat/upside-down sea-going
navy with living/intelligent ships. The focus was on one particular ship that existed simultaneously on the upper & upside-down planes. At the end of the story the enemy's cannon fire broke the keel of our hero ship and it died.

I can't really remember the cover art other than it was childishly simple lines. The author was not very experienced but the story was a trippy, original theme.

Comment: [Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland) has some of the same themes, but not a navy, as far as I can recall.

Comment: Did you read it in English, or perhaps Spanish or some other language?

Answer (score 25):

I wonder if this might be *[The Two-Space War](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?48978)* by Leo Frankowski and Dave Grossman. Published in 2004 it is more or less consistent with "around 2000", and it includes most of the plot points, especially Napoleonic-style wooden navies going to war in a two-dimensional universe.

From a review on [poetrybase](http://www.poetrybase.info/reviews/000/003.shtml):

> The background premise behind the book is that mankind has sought the
> stars and found them. But not through high technology and moving
> through some fourth dimension of space. Instead, **mankind found a
> collapsed, two-dimensional version of the universe** where everything
> was much closer together. Unfortunately, high technology didn’t work
> in this Two-Space. Instead, **men built wooden ships coated with an
> intelligent mold** that allowed them to have a three-dimensional bubble
> of air and warmth as they sailed from planetary island to planetary
> island in the sea of this two-dimensional universe. Thus, we were back
> to wooden ships and iron men.

Thanks to FuzzyBoots providing a link to an [online version](https://archive.org/details/twospacewar0000gros/page/166/mode/2up) of the text, I've been able to refresh my memory of the plot. I believe that the OP is recalling specifically the  sinking of the "Kestrel", which takes place over the first six chapters of the book. The Kestrel was jumped by a Guldur ship, and received major damage both on the up-side (above Flatland) and the downside (below). In particular the Keel was in bad shape. The ship's carpenter explains:

> Sir, the vacuum-cursed dogs cut our Keel! The Keel’s only holdin’
> together with splinters. Lady Elbereth’s Gift, the Moss on the Keel,
> is all that seems to be holdin’ the charge. And Sir,  the Ship is dyin’! Only the Ship, old Kestrel herself is holdin’ us in two-space. If not for her, we would’a popped into vacuum days ago, and she can’t keep it up much longer. She’s dyin’ sir!”

The Kestrel just manages to hold itself together long enough to

> tempt the Guldurian ship to board it, and then heroically destroy itself, taking its enemies with it.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/twospacewar0000gros?